# htaccess to Caddy rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caddy

I'm trying to install Cachet on a Caddy server however when I try to access the webpage it tries to go to /setup, but Caddy gives me '404 Not Found'.

For Apache they say you have to use this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/Cachet/public">
    Require all granted 
    # Used by Apache 2.4
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But how would I do this in my Caddyfile? I guess it has something to do with the symbolic links as there is no actual setup folder.

.htacces of Cachet

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: is there a .htaccess file on the root of the website?  or in the /setup directory?

Comment: Yep done, sorry.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post in the .htaccess its very difficult to see in a comment

Comment: If you post your question to https://caddy.community/ you may have a bit more luck.  You need to add a rewrite section to your caddyfile to do the same as what the .htaccess file is doing.

Comment: I'll do that as well, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how would I do this in my Caddyfile? I guess it has something to do with the symbolic links as there is no actual setup folder.

In fact it is not about symbolic links, but *URL Rewriting*.
Cachet is a Web application developed using Laravel 5, and every HTTP request is routed to `public/index.php`.

So the way to achieve you installation is:

- Enabling .htaccess.
- Enabling mod_rewrite on Apache

So all the HTTP requests will be routed to `public/index.php` and it will call the `App/Http/Controllers/SetupController`. It's not about a symbolic link.

I do not know Caddy so I can't explain you how to configure it, but there is a [Caddy post](https://caddy.community/t/apache-mod-rewrite-to-caddyfile/2503/4) where someone needs to enable mod_rewrite in Caddy.